# Want to store python dictionary to Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, dictionary

The below code fetch the data from CSV file which is shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXWc6.png) and store in python dictionary

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import csv
try:
   conn=MongoClient()
   print("Connected Successfully")
except:
   print("Not Connected")

db=conn.nestedDynamicData
collection=db.nested   

with open('tbl_actual_demand_met.csv') as f:
csv_list = [[val.strip() for val in r.split(",")] for r in f.readlines()]
(_, *header), *data = csv_list
csv_dict = {}
for row in data:
    key, *values = row

    if key not in csv_dict:
    csv_dict[key] = []

csv_dict[key].append({key: value for key, value in zip(header, values)})
print(csv_dict)

collection.insert_many([csv_dict])
```

The above Code gives output as follows:

```
{'01-01-2020': {'name': 'x', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '223.2',
            'name': 'y', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '823.2',
            'name': 'z', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '23.2'},
            '02-01-2020': {'name': 'a', 'time': '00:05:00', 'value': '273.2',
            'name': 'b', 'time': '00:05:00', 'value': '23.2'}}
```

But when i have inserted it in mongodb using insert_many() the subDocument is inserted inside [0] [1] [2] i have attached [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo5IO.png)
I dont want to insert data inside [0] [1] [2], Please somebody help me to remove this [0] [1] [2]

Comment: You have not been clear on what you *do* want the output to be

Comment: When i store the dictionary in MongoDB database their [0] [1] [2] sub elements are created, So i dont want that sub elements in MongoDB Database

Comment: I understand what you don't want. but what DO you want

Comment: There can only be 1 element in each dictionary with the same key. so for "01-01-2020", how do you plan on differentiating between the entries?

Comment: Also, I dont think your code output is correct. Based on the code, I would expect: '01-01-2020': [{'name': 'x', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '223.2'},
           { 'name': 'y', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '823.2'},
           { 'name': 'z', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '23.2'}]...